# Solving for y in $4+x^3+y^3-3xy = 0$

Tags: problem-solving, cubics

I was trying to solve for $y$ in this equation: $4+x^3+y^3-3xy = 0$. I put it into WolframAlpha and it gave me an complicated answer. It appears like it used the cubic formula, except when I tried to view the steps on Wolfram, it showed this strange substitution: [image]

So my question is how would you finish solving this, or is there another simpler way that doesn't involve creating a new variable like $λ$?

Comment: This is known as Cardano's method, or Tartaglia's method (and it's where the cubic formula comes from).  If you Google these terms you will find plenty of examples and explanation.